# How can a left and right margin be added to the admin bar without access to "...wp-includes/admin-bar.php"?

Tags: css, admin-menu, admin-bar

I do not have access to *"wp-includes/admin-bar.php"* due to security restrictions placed by my host, they have advised me to use css stylesheets which I am not familiar with.

I am looking to add a left and right sided margin to the links (login/register/sign out etc) in the admin bar so they align with the main content and display correctly on mobile devices.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you imply editing core file - that's considered really bad practice. This does sound like something to be done with CSS style. How did you want to change it precisely, if not with CSS?

Comment: I can usually tweek existing css to achieve the designs I want, but in this instance I do not have access the the admin-php.php file so I don't have existing code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using firefox, chrome or safari to browse your site, you can inspect each page's elements. For example in chrome you can right click anywhere on your browser window and select "inspect element". Now you should be able to see the code for that page and find out the css classes that the admin bar uses.

For example:

```
<div id="wpadminbar" class="" role="navigation">
</div>
```

Once you know what classes to target with css, you can edit your style.css to change those elements. You will need to have some basic css skills. You will also need to use the attribute "!important" in your css to make sure it's overriding the default wordpress css.

Comment: `function style_admin_bar() {

    echo '<style type="text/css">

 #wpadminbar .quicklinks {

  margin-right: 13.5%;

  margin-left: 13.5%;

 }

 </style>

   ';

}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'style_admin_bar' ); // backend

add_action( 'wp_head', 'style_admin_bar' ); // frontend`  - Adding this to functions.php is the closest I've got so far, it displays correctly now on desktop but still out of screen on mobile devices. Almost there I think.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this to style.css:

`#wpadminbar {
    min-width: 0;
}`

and this to functions.php:

```
function style_admin_bar() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
#wpadminbar .quicklinks {

    margin-right: 13.5%;
    margin-left: 13.5%;
}
</style> } add_action( 'admin_head', 'style_admin_bar' ); // backend
add_action( 'wp_head', 'style_admin_bar' ); // frontend
```